# I can't remove old kernel image - Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, dpkg

My `uname -a` returns following.

```
Linux <hidden> 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to upgrade the packages, it fails by showing following errors regarding an old kernel.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 libgd3 php-gd php-mbstring php-mysql php-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-dev php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd
  php7.0-json php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-soap php7.0-tidy php7.0-xml php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-zip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 142623 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic (3.13.0-68.111) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-68-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: amd64-microcode: unsupported kernel version!
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_30aiDQ/lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_30aiDQ/lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
dpkg-query: error: package 'grub-legacy-ec2' is not installed
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 exited with return code 10
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic (3.13.0-68.111) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/memtest86+.bin
dpkg-query: error: package 'grub-legacy-ec2' is not installed
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 exited with return code 10
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: Output of `apt list --installed | grep grub`

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

grub-common/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22 amd64 [installed]
grub-gfxpayload-lists/xenial,now 0.7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
grub-pc/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22 amd64 [installed]
grub-pc-bin/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22 amd64 [installed,automatic]
grub2-common/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.22 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: See how to resolve error code 1 : https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/

Comment: You have a really old version of grub installed (v1), but an error message reports `grub-legacy-ec2` is not installed so installing that *may* fix your issue (*I haven't used old grub in years which is why the hesitation*)

Comment: I've tried to auto remove, but this also fails with the same errors. Regarding the grub, my present version 2. As you can see the running kernel is 4.4.0-116-generic.

Comment: Is there a way to remove them manually, like moving/deleting. I dont' know the location of the folders.

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep grub` edit your question for output please.

Comment: @nobody I've added the command output. please check the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -P grub-legacy-ec2
```

To get rid of possible remains files.

It would be better from me to ask over dpkg.

If errorrs pop up, but only when

```
sudo mv /etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 $HOME
```

Remove
The same please for

```
/boot/grub/default
```

and for

/boot/grub/menu.lst

then dry to remove the old kernel

```
sudo dpkg -P linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic
```

Next is important so you do not end up without any bootloader.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub-pc-bin grub2-common
```

And now install grub2 bootcode. We don't know which one is present in mbr.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

[grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

and at least

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I've removed the dpkg status files' description of the said kernel images and removed the menu.lst file. I haven't restarted the OS yet. Now the errors disappeared. Do you think any booting problem appear?

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep "Disk /|/dev/" | sed "s#^/dev/#Part /dev/#" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -n1 -IX sudo sh -c "hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 \"%x\" \"\\n\"' X | xargs -n1 -IY sh -c \"case  \"Y\" in '48b4') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.96 ;; 'aa75' | '5272') echo X: GRUB Legacy ;; '7c3c') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.97 oder v1.98 ;; '020') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.99 ;; *) echo X: Kein GRUB Y ;; esac\""` will show if grub2 is correct set in the MBR

Comment: Its output: 
```/dev/vda: GRUB 2 v1.99

/dev/vda1: Kein GRUB 00

/dev/vda14: Kein GRUB 31d2

/dev/vda15: Kein GRUB 6f74

/dev/vdb: Kein GRUB 00```

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Looks fine.